# How to write a conditonal regressional loss function based on binary cross entropy loss for Keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am building a key-point detection system of the human face. The goal is to have an image of the face be input into the model, and the model then detects anatomical landmarks in the image (eyes, nose) and outputs the pixel coordinates of the landmarks that are visible. There are three targets per landmark: x, y, visible. X and Y are the pixel coordinates, and visible is whether the landmark is in the image or not. The plan is to first have a binary cross entropy loss between predicted visibility and true visibility. Then, the second loss is a regression loss (I'm using MAPE) between the x,y coordinates and the targets. However, the regression loss would only be calculated for landmarks that are visible. The loss would look something like:

```
#Pseudo-code
def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    if y_true[2] == 1
       #Probability that landmark is in image
       #Compute binary cross entropy loss
       #Compute MAPE regression loss
       Total_loss = Binary_loss + MAPE_loss
       return Total_loss

    else:
       Total_loss = Binary loss
       return Total_loss
```

Once the loss function is written, how would I go about implementing it in code? I know how to create models for each problem (checking the coordinates, and separately checking the visibility), but I'm not sure exactly how to go about combining the two heads with the conditional loss function. How would I combine the layers (Conv, Flatten, Dense for each head) to get the desired output? Thank you!

EDIT:
I'm not able to upload the data, but here is an image of it. The first 9 columns are the coordinates, and visibility of the landmarks. The last column is the corresponding image which has been flattened.  [image] When I load in the data for training, these are the steps I do:

```
###Read in data file
file = "Directory/file.csv"
train_data = pd.read_csv(file)
###Convert each coordinate column to type float64
train_data['xreye'] = train_data['xreye'].astype(np.float64)
...
###Convert image column to string type
train_data['Image'] = train_data['Image'].astype(str)

#Image is feature, other values are labels to predict later
#Image column values are strings, also some missing values, have to split
##string by space and append it and handle missing values
imag = []
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    img = train_data['Image'][i].split(' ')
    img = ['0' if x == '' else x for x in img]      
    imag.append(img) 
#Reshape and convert to float value
image_list = np.array(imag,dtype = 'uint8')
X_train = image_list.reshape(-1,256,256,1)

####Get pixel coordinates and visibility targets
training = train_data[['xreye','yreye','reyev','xleye','yleye','leyev','xtsept','ytsept','tseptv']]
y_train = []
for i in range(len(train_data)):
    y = training.iloc[i,:]
    y_train.append(y)

y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype='float')
```

EDIT: Model code, loss function, and fit method.

```
###Loss function
visuals_mask = [False, False, True] * 3
def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    visuals_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, visuals_mask, axis=1)
    visuals_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, visuals_mask, axis=1)
    visuals_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(visuals_true, visuals_pred)
    visuals_loss = tf.reduce_mean(visuals_loss)

    coords_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1)
    coords_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1)
    coords_loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsolutePercentageError(coords_true, coords_pred)
    coords_loss = tf.reduce_mean(coords_loss)

    return coords_loss + visuals_loss
####Model code
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(256,256,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='linear'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_func)

###Model fit
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('C:/Users/Cloud/.spyder-py3/x_y_shift/weights/vis_coords_TEST.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, mode = 'min', save_best_only=True)
out = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5,batch_size=4,validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Comment: Can you please share the shape of your input and output data? And is this a single or multi output model?

Comment: Sure, the input is an image of shape (256,256,1). The output would be (righteyeX, righteyeY, righteyeVis, lefteyeX, lefteyeY, lefteyeVis, noseX, noseY, noseVis), output shape (1,8) for each image input. So I guess it would be a multi output model. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure beacuse I don't have data to reproduce the problem but these are the steps in my head:

1. Use [boolean masking](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) to get the 2, 5 and 8. indexes from the output:

```py
visuals_mask_ = [False, False, True] * 3

# in the loss function
visuals_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, visuals_mask_, axis=-1) # do the same with preds
```

2. Compute the loss for the visuals

```py
visuals_loss = binary_crossentropy(visuals_true, visuals_pred) # use sparse if that's the case
```

3. Get the coordinates' outputs just like we did for visuals but with reversed `visuals_mask`. I believe `tf.boolean_mask(y_true, tf.math.logical_not(visuals_mask_, axis=-1))` should work.
4. Compute MAPE for the rest (`coords_true` and `coords_pred`)
5. Get the means for both losses by `tf.reduce_mean`
6. Get sum of losses and return it

I hope these will provide some insight.

**Edit:**
I tried the following and seems like it's working:

```py
y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(32, 9))
y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(32, 9))

visuals_mask = [False, False, True] * 3

def loss_func(y_true, y_pred):
    visuals_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, visuals_mask, axis=1)
    visuals_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, visuals_mask, axis=1)
    visuals_loss = binary_crossentropy(visuals_true, visuals_pred)
    visuals_loss = tf.reduce_mean(visuals_loss)

    coords_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1)
    coords_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1)
    coords_loss = mean_absolute_percentage_error(coords_true, coords_pred)
    coords_loss = tf.reduce_mean(coords_loss)

    return coords_loss + visuals_loss

loss_func(y_true, y_pred)
```

What I assumed here is:

- Your output has actually has length of 9 (`(batch_size, 9)`).
- Custom loss calculations may differ in this demonstration and actual training because of [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager).

**Edit 2:**
I tried it with this kind of model and it's seems to work:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(4, 10, data_format='channels_last', input_shape=(256, 256, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam', loss=loss_func)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried using this loss function and simple model, but I ended up getting this error: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy'> to Tensor. I'm guessing it's because I'm not shaping the input correctly with tensors. For y_train, I'm assuming I would just do y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train), but what would I do for y_pred? I'm not sure how to input that during the training process.

Comment: I think assumed your data correctly. Can you show your code please? The model, the `fit` method and the loss function. BTW you do not need to use `conver_to_tensor` in the loss function during training, because they are already tensors. Just try the loss function I wrote.

Comment: Hello, I've added the code you requested. I've tried both my model, and the simple one you tested but to no avail. I still get the same error for each. I've also tried changing the batch size from 4 to 1, but that didn't work either. I'm also using Python 3.8, not sure if that might affect certain code but just thought I'd toss it out there. Thank you again for all of your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I noticed that I used BinaryCrossentropy() in the loss function. However, when I switched it to binary_crossentropy(), it led to this error: TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Equal', got 'auto' of type 'str' instead. Error: Expected float32, got 'auto' of type 'str' instead. Looking online, it recommends using loss_func() instead of loss_func in model.compile(). However, when I try that it says: TypeError: loss_func() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'.

Comment: Hello, I have just copied your model and loss function code and did these and it just worked:

1. I removed callbacks
2. Changed the lines to `visuals_loss = binary_crossentropy(visuals_true, visuals_pred)` and `coords_loss = mean_absolute_percentage_error(coords_true, coords_pred)` in loss func and it started to train right away.

Comment: Hello, that did the trick! Thank you so much for all of your help! I just had one more question more for understanding. In the loss function the two lines ```coords_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1)
    coords_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, ~np.array(visuals_mask), axis=1) ```, does this make it so that the coordinates are only predicted when the boolean returns true (landmark is visible in image)? I'm a bit unfamiliar with the ~np.array notation. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm very glad it worked, you're welcome! :) Yes, the `visuals_mask` is being used to pick only 3, 6 and 9. items from the output of the model (the visual values). Using that, we calculate loss only for the vusials. `~np.array(visuals_mask)` is just for getting the opposite of the `visuals_mask` so that we can compute the loss only for the coordinates.